# Task Runner Explorer for "Visual Studio for Mac"

Tags: macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I have a solution for multiple .Net Core projects and I am using a Windows VM in order to use VS2017 IDE.

I just got the brand new Visual Studio for Mac Release (ver 7.0).

I'm trying to switch to this IDE but something is missing in it : the Task Runner Explorer.

I can't found it in VS for mac. The Task Runner Explorer is responsible of multiple compilation / task that are done automatically in background on build / file save / etc.

Have you an idea on how I can get back this task runner explorer or something similar in VS for mac ?

Thanks !

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-mac-relnotes#feedback Microsoft has the channels open for you to submit feedback like this.

Comment: Did you find a way to use the Task Runner Explorer ? Thanks

Comment: Not at all.. and due to that, i'm stil using a Windows VM instead of Visual studio for mac :(

Comment: I think I should do the same, I actively seek a solution and post it here if I find it

Comment: Visual Studio Code supports build tasks: https://code.visualstudio.com. It's not as full-featured as Visual Studio but depending on what you need to do, that could be an option.